# Running SAGA GDAL libraries from QGIS V3.14.16-Pi on system with admin restrictions

Tags: qgis, gdal, qgis-processing

I am having difficulties running the SAGA raster toolbox io_gdal libraries within QGIS (V3.14.16- PI) on a managed Windows PC (software installed by corporate IT). My IT assistant has asked me if the problem is connected with the location of the temporary folder that GDAL attempts to write intermediate results to, but I have changed the path to a folder with write access and this has not resolved the problem.

I have pasted in the log that is being generated below. I can get SAGA to run the same applications without any issues, so I am not sure what the problem is. Perhaps finding out where the libraries are installed would help as they appear to be in a folder that is being blocked by my IT policies? I am a fairly experienced GIS user but not an expert on how these packages are installed on a desktop PC.

```
io_gdal 0 -TRANSFORM 1 -RESAMPLING 3 -GRIDS "C:/Users/2345340/Temp/processing_NxfdVC/b76977a145934c20b330298b2e451b07/249000351000DSM.sgrd" -FILES "C:/Users/2345340/Documents/GIS/BWLidar/249000_351000_DSM.asc"
io_gdal 0 -TRANSFORM 1 -RESAMPLING 3 -GRIDS "C:/Users/2345340/Temp/processing_NxfdVC/5a7d1282f7cf46e1ba57d466f2d8baee/278000331000DSM.sgrd" -FILES "C:/Users/2345340/Documents/GIS/BWLidar/278000_331000_DSM.asc"
grid_tools "Mosaicking" -TARGET_DEFINITION 0 -GRIDS "C:/Users/2345340/Temp/processing_NxfdVC/b76977a145934c20b330298b2e451b07/249000351000DSM.sgrd;C:/Users/2345340/Temp/processing_NxfdVC/5a7d1282f7cf46e1ba57d466f2d8baee/278000331000DSM.sgrd" -NAME "Mosaic" -TYPE 7 -RESAMPLING 0 -OVERLAP 1 -BLEND_DIST 10.0 -MATCH 0 -TARGET_USER_SIZE 100.0 -TARGET_USER_FITS 0 -TARGET_OUT_GRID "C:/Users/2345340/Documents/GIS/test.sdat"
```

> This program is blocked by group policy. For more information, contact your system administrator.
> Execution completed in 0.17 seconds

Comment: "*This program is blocked by group policy.*" is the key. Your IT people developed the Applocker policy and installed the QGIS/Saga software They should be able to figure out where it got installed to and whitelist what they need to (everything in install location, or perhaps they're whitelisting exes and dlls specifically and missed some.)

Comment: Thanks, surprisingly the IT department fixed the permissions on the Applocker to allow the program to run through their firewall. All is working now.